# IntelliJ 12 + Gradle 1.3 - Basic Gradle syntax seems non-functional

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am attempting to play around with Gradle integration in IntelliJ Idea (Ultimate) v12.

It seems even if $GRADLE_HOME is configured properly, basic syntax such as 'apply', 'dependencies', etc. is not recognized.

[image]

I would seem like the solution should be something simple. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem until this morning.  I did the following steps and it solved itself:

- added the root build.gradle file (we have several) to the JetGradle tab and refreshed
- updated to IDEA 12.0.1 (it restarts and reindexes)

I think doing the first one and restarting may be enough, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is a big improvement. Only gripe is I cannot navigate to symbol definitions such as 'apply', 'jar', etc. But this may likely be a configuration issue with my local environment.

Comment: I can't get this working. I have configured gradle from start in idea 12, and have this weird red errors

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't currently offer syntax completion for Gradle build scripts. All you get is the standard Groovy support.

Comment: So the red is part of that, too?

Comment: Not sure why you get these errors. I only get errors for unresolvable packages and types, because IDEA doesn't understand the class path for a Gradle build script. What error messages do you get? Maybe best ask on the IDEA forum or submit an issue.

Comment: Error tooltip reads 'Cannot resolve symbol x'. The display is a bit better with 12.0.1 (per Quartz's answer below), e.g. the text is not a distracting red color. However the same tooltip exists.

Comment: I've always had "Cannot resolve symbol 'dependencies'", etc. I've added proper Gradle home location to Project Settings > Gradle section. Every month I search the web to try and find a solution and give up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Intellij 13 and have had similar problems.  What I noticed was, creating a new Project from Intellij (i.e. new Groovy Project or Gradle project), I get the syntax error markers.  I also have noticed it didn't do a good job pulling in Gradle dependencies.

On the other hand, if I Import a Project through an already created build.gradle file, the syntax error markings go away and the dependencies seem to play more nicely.  Not sure if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

With Intellij 14 and Gradle 2.3 I found that adding `{$GRADLE_HOME}/lib` and `{$GRADLE_HOME}/lib/plugins` as libraries in my project settings got rid of all the warnings like "dependencies cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure".